# Laravel Models One to Many relation is not being established

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I am doing a learning project. very new to Laravel. So I have a User and a Company profile CRUD. Company belongsTo User and User may have many Company. So in my User model I implemented this

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Company;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    //relation with company
    public function company(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Company','id');
    }
}
```

and in company model i did

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    //table name
    protected $table='companies';
    //primary keys
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    //relation with User Model

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Models\User::class);
}
```

My company profile controller is

```
public function index()
    {
        //Showing companies under user

        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        $companies=$user->company;

        return view('company.profile')->with('companies', $companies);
    }
```

But when it comes to execution, it seems like

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Models\User::class);
}
```

this function in Company model is not working. I mean a company is getting assigned to one user but it should be like many companies in one user. What did I do wrong?

Btw my User model location is App/Model/User.php, and I declared the user model path in auth.php .My Company.php Model location is App/Company.php. please have a look and try to help this newb out. Many thanks.

Comment: Since there can be many companies, I'd personally rename `public function company(){` to `public function companies(){`. Try using `return $this->hasMany('App\Company');` instead of `return $this->hasMany('App\Company','id');` - Eloquent will know that the field name needs to be `user_id` in your company (you're basically telling it to use `id` as that relation field, which means "company with id #1 belongs to user #1, company #2 belongs to user #2)

Comment: okay. but if I dont use `return $this->hasMany('App\Company','id');` it gives me an error

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'companies.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `companies` where `companies`.`user_id` = 2 and `companies`.`user_id` is not null)
 @kerbholz

Comment: Then add that column to your company migration/table. How did you relate a company to a user before? What field have you been using? Id? (Usually, `id` is an autoincrement column that identifies a company, then you'd have a field/column `user_id` that relates that company to a user)

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it real good from your explanation @kerbholz

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand your question but my answer may be help you

users belongs to company

in model user

---

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');

}
```

maby be wrong code

---

```
//relation with company
public function company(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Company','id'); // not Id foreign_key as company_id
}
```

this is true but you can write it better as

```
public function index()
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $user = User::find($user_id)->with('company');
    //$companies=$user->company;

    return view('company.profile', compact('user');
}
```